# SQL server hieracy bottom-top comboinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a query to derive all bottom to top combinations in a hierachy: Every entity has a owner and a owner percentage - I would like to be able to query bottom entities with all combinations of owners at every level:

```
Data:
Entity      Owner      Percentage
F1          F2         x
F2          F3         y
F3          F4         z
```

I would like the result to be:

```
Entity      Owner      Percentage
F1          F2         x
F1          F3         x*y
F1          F4         x*y*z
F2          F3         y
F2          F4         y*z
F3          F4         z
```

I have tried using a cte doing the hook at the bottom layer, but this only gives me the previous (-1 level) entity, and this should support undefined levels in the hierachy.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: x, y, z are integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with d as
(
    select t.Entity, t.Owner, t.Percentage
    from t

    union all

    select d.Entity, t.Owner, t.Percentage * d.Percentage 
    from d
    inner join t on d.Owner = t.Entity
)
select *
from d
order by d.Entity, d.Owner
```